# MSOffice-Outlook Add ins - Custom Form Region not displaying

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, office-addins

I am developing an Add In for Outlook 2013. When I try to add a form region for custom message class, the form region does not replace the default reading pane view until I "pop out" one the messages. After the message is "popped out" the custom form region is then shown in both the separate pop out window and the reading pane (for all messages where the form region applies) - in other words, everything works after I "pop out" one of the messages.

I have already tried to change the FormRegionType to Replace and ReplaceAll, but I am having the same issue. The only FormRegionType that has given me any luck (e.g. not "popping out" the window) is Adjoining, but then I have the problem where the default reading pane is joined with my custom form region.

I need this form region to be the default for this message class.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you show your Form Region manifest XML please?

Comment: Where do you find the manifest XML code?